# CSS Image and Div won't stay inline

Tags: html, css, inline, display

UPDATE: So I've created [a JSFFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tkr2w9jg/1/) and it works perfectly on there as long as the "Bio" and "Reason" paragraphs are short. But as soon as they are substantially larger than the image, they refuse to go inline and will go onto the next line.

I am trying to get an image to sit next to a DIV that contains two paragraphs. For some reason, it will not go inline and I can't figure out why.

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="complete_entry">
    <a name="poet106"></a>
    <h1 class="lexpomo" id="poet_list"><a href='#poet106'>Poet Name</a><br /></h1>
    <p class="lexpomo" id="sign_up_date">
        2016-05-29 22:29:56
    </p>
    <img src="http://localhost/accents/wp-content/uploads/lexpomo/inkwell.svg" class="lexpomo" id="poet_avatar" />
    <div id="poet_list_block">
        <p class="lexpomo" id="poet_bio">
            <strong>Bio: 
            </strong><br />
            Paragraph-length bio.
        </p>
        <p class="lexpomo" id="poet_reason">
            <strong>Reason for signing up: </strong><br />
            Paragraph-length reason.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.complete_entry {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

#sign_up_date {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 10pt;
}

#poet_bio, #poet_reason {
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

h1#poet_list,
h1#poet_list a{
    margin: 30px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
}

img.lexpomo#poet_avatar {
    width: 100px;
    max-height: 200px;
    min-height: 50px;
    display: inline;
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    background-color: black;
}

#poet_list_block {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    clear: none;
}
```

I'm running this on WordPress, but I don't think that should matter for this question.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `float: left`  means `display: block !important`, so doesn't matter if you put `display: inline`, don't work like this. Avoid to use floats to layouts and all will run ok.

Comment: The same `#id` can only occur once per document. You are repeating `#poet_list`. Make it a class instead.

Comment: could you please create a jsfiddle?

Comment: @marcos-pérez-gude That didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: If it works in the fiddle and not in your local enviromet you should have something messing up with it. Try removing things until it works on local.

Comment: You jsfiddle looks fine to me, I think you should reset the User-Agent CSS by using https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: @c14l Thanks for the advice! It didn't fix my problem, but it's good to know.

Comment: @pascal-goldbach I created a JSFiddle; the code works on JSFiddle, but not on my local server. I don't know what could be causing the problem!

Comment: Update: Apparently this has to do with the size of the paragraphs inside of the DIV. Check out the updated JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that since there is no width specified on your `poet_list_block`, and your `p` elements contain enough text to fill an entire line, the `p` elements define the width of the whole block and make it 100%. This means that there is no room for the block on the current line, and this is why it drops down to the next line.

From your question it seems like you want the two paragraphs to be in a single square `div` sitting to the right of the image, rather than having them on the next line or floating independently (and wrapping under the image). The easiest way to do that would be to use CSS `table` styling instead of floats.

**Screenshot of Result:**

[image]

**Working Live Demo:**

```css
#sign_up_date {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 10pt;
}

#poet_bio, #poet_reason {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 0;
}

h1#poet_list,
h1#poet_list a{
    margin: 30px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
}

img.lexpomo#poet_avatar {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    max-height: 200px;
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
}

.bio_container {
  display: table;
}

.bio_container > * {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="complete_entry">
    <a name="poet106"></a>
    <h1 class="lexpomo" id="poet_list"><a href='#poet106'>Poet Name</a><br /></h1>
    <p class="lexpomo" id="sign_up_date">
        2016-05-29 22:29:56
    </p>
    <div class="bio_container">
    
    <img src="http://localhost/accents/wp-content/uploads/lexpomo/inkwell.svg" class="lexpomo" id="poet_avatar" />
    <div id="poet_list_block">
        <p class="lexpomo" id="poet_bio">
            <strong>Bio: 
            </strong><br />
            Paragraph-length bio. Paragraph-length bio. Paragraph-length bio. Paragraph-length bio. Paragraph-length bio. Paragraph-length bio. Paragraph-length bio. Paragraph-length bio. Paragraph-length bio. Paragraph-length bio. Paragraph-length bio. Paragraph-length bio. Paragraph-length bio. Paragraph-length bio. Paragraph-length bio. Paragraph-length bio. Paragraph-length bio. Paragraph-length bio. Paragraph-length bio. 
        </p>
        <p class="lexpomo" id="poet_reason">
            <strong>Reason for signing up: </strong><br />
            Paragraph-length reason.
        </p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/6upL7gzc/

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a much better method.